# XAMPP: Requests take far longer when connecting to a MySQL database

Tags: performance, php, mysql, xampp

I'm developing in PHP and MySQL locally using XAMPP on Windows. The web site is fairly fast when not connecting to any database. However, when I connect to the MySQL database, a simple request now takes approximentaly a second.

Note: This is not the case on my remote Debian vServer. My vServer handles requests fast, no matter if using a database or not.

I use Windows 8 x64 and the latest version of XAMPP and I did not commit any changed to the configuration files.

What could be the cause of this bad performance?^

Edit: This is the connection code I use:

```
$sql = new SqlConnection($cfgDbHost, $cfgDbUser, $cfgDbPassword);
$sql->setCurrentDatabase($cfgDbDatabase);

[...]

    class SqlConnection
    {
        private $Link, $CurrentDatabase, $IsConnected;

        function SqlConnection($host = 'localhost', $user = 'root', $pass = '')
        {
            $this->Link = @mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
            $this->IsConnected = $this->Link != NULL;
        }
        function setCurrentDatabase($database)
        {
            if (@mysql_select_db($database, $this->Link))
            {
                $this->CurrentDatabase = $database;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        [...]
```

Comment: Use a SQL Browser (i.e.: HeidiSQL) and run some test queries directly against the database... do it on the server and from a remote computer and compare the times. It could be network, it could be memory, it could be MySQLs settings.

Comment: Using HeidiSQL, a query takes almost zero time. phpMyAdmin is also fast. I'll post the connection code.

Comment: I uploaded the relevant code. Also I'd like to note, that the connection alone is the part that takes all the time. Even when no queries are fired, it takes like a second longer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the Windows Hosts file here -

C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Make sure that this line is in there...

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

And make sure that this line is commented out...

```
::1 localhost
```

Sometimes issues with IPv6 and/or localhost resolves can cause timeouts like this.

Also see if -

```
$host = '127.0.0.1'
```

makes any difference.

Comment: Changing $host to 127.0.0.1 really helped. Seems to be a DNS problem. Thank you!

Comment: yup that connect using 127.0.0.1 was it.. Thanks!!